# double free or corruption (fasttop), With casting pointers to map down a class

Tags: c++, memory

In trying to figure out a more complicated issue, where the `static_cast<Derived*>(base_class)` returns an object with random `Derived` class variables. In trying to create a simple example, I found the following code is buggy, so I was wondering why. Currently it returns,

```
2
*** Error in `./main': double free or corruption (fasttop): 0x0000000000d55c20 ***
...
```

Here's an online copy: [C++ Online Compiler](https://www.mycompiler.io/view/C5679sD)

Here's the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <map>

class Base {
    
};

class Derived : public Base {
    public:
    float a = 2.0f;
};

std::map<int, std::unique_ptr<Base>> mapOfClasses;

int main() {
    std::unique_ptr<Base> baseUP = std::make_unique<Derived>();
    
    int key = 0;
    mapOfClasses.emplace(key, move(baseUP));
    
    auto it = mapOfClasses.find(key);
    Base* basePtr = it->second.get();

    Derived* derivedPtr = static_cast<Derived*>(basePtr);
    
    std::cout << derivedPtr->a << std::endl;
    
    delete basePtr;
    delete derivedPtr;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You should not delete either `basePtr` or `derivedPtr` neither of these own the object.

Comment: In general, you should not `delete` a pointer you didn't create with `new`.

Comment: The entire purpose of `unique_ptr` and `shared_ptr` is that so you don't need to `delete` anything. That's what they're for.

Comment: Thanks, I just noticed that. Good point. I had added it because of that error, but now removing it solves the error.

Comment: There is still the issue of deleting a pointer via a pointer to its base class. Add Destructors to `Base` and `Derived` that print out unique messages to see which destructor is being called. If it is not `Derived` you have a problem.

Comment: Seems like you need a primer on what `unique_ptr` actually is and does.

Answer (score 2):

Problem is that you delete the pointer three times. Once in the destructor of unique pointer and twice explicitly. More than once is too much. The behaviour of the program is undefined.

Two of those times to delete through a pointer to base. That also results in undefined behaviour because the destructor of the base isn't virtual.